# snowflake time-travel micro-partition can rewriteable when update？

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, time-travel

As we all know, in snowflake one mini-partition maybe rewrite/replace when user **update** the row in the mini-partition. How snowflake handle the mini-partition in time-travel table space when user **update**?

I think snowflake need to mark the row which has updated in the old time-travel mini-partition, and it will create a new  time-travel mini-partition for the rows which has updated, considering it implement time-travel and stream.

I want to know that Because: if time-travel micro-partition can rewriteable, maybe is not safety for my customer's requirement. If it is not rewriteable, maybe the query for time-travel is not efficient for my customer's requirement too.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure why you think that how Snowflake works “under the covers” would affect safety or performance in any way that would be of interest to your customer - but, given that, Snowflake is insert-only at the micro partition level. Basically, if a user “updates” a record then the new values are inserted and the old version is marked as no longer current

Comment: For time travel, my customer say LOG is safety, SO he think time travel is just log, and streaming support by time travel, each mini-partition must not overlap in data version. But If time travel is only log and the mini-partition in time travel append only, the time travel will have performance problem.  And snowflake maybe using some technology,  such as snowflake will rewrite old mini-partition, mark the record as update if a user “updates” a record, then create a new mini-partition for the record, each micro partition can not overlap. It have good performance for time travel and streaming.

Comment: Inshort, my customer will using update / time travel / streaming in a table, he is worried about maybe some problem (safey, cost, performance)) after migrate data to snowflake

Comment: It's still not clear to me what the relevance is to how Snowflake has implemented any of it's functionality. Snowflake has clearly documented its capabilities and either they meet your client's requirements or they don't - which you can discover by doing a PoC if you wanted to. By analogy, it's like you wanting to buy a car that can do 0-60 in under 5 seconds and instead of taking out on the road and trying it, you want to look at the source code for the ECU

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think your are right,  time-travel just access the old version of metadata, and micro-partition never real delete (marked as no longer current as you say) until retention period expires.